# How to access the same column for all data frames inside a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have an object like this:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4))
d3 <- data.frame(y1=c(7,8,9),y2=c(5,2,6))
my.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)
names(my.list) <- c("d1","d2","d3")
```

Is there a way to access the column `y2` of all data frames inside the list once?

Something like this:

```
my.list[["d1"]]$y2
```

But this only works for one data frame at a time

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
lapply(my.list, '[[', 'y2')
```

Or use `sapply` to get the output as a matrix

```
sapply(my.list, `[[`, 'y2')
```

Comment: saved me a lot of time. looking for this for hours. Thanks :)